This is the house where I had a party last night. (ellipsis of antecedent, where; or substitution by relativizer that)


This is the house that I had a party last night.




This is the house I had a party last night.




This is where I had a party last night.


I wonder if theese sentences are grammatically or idiomatically acceptable.

1 and 3 are OK but 2 is not idiomatic.

I just omitted 'where' in 2. They say relative adverb or antecedent can be omitted. Wonder why 2 is not idiomatic.

You could say This is the house I had a party in last night.

I think 1 also needs 'in': This is the house that I had a party in last night.

"They say relative adverb or antecedent can be omitted" —Maybe tell more about this in the question? "Where" isn't an adverb or an antecedent, but if we can see more of the advice you're referencing, maybe we can help explain it.

This is the place I had a party last night. (O) vs. This is the house I had a party last night. (X) Why house is not possible?
